# Python script to process a text file and create a csv file

Tags: python, csv, text-processing

I have a text file that has data in a certain format as given below:

```
Name : John Doe
age  : 30
Job  : Accountant
```

I need this data in a csv format like :

```
John Doe,30,Accountant
```

What is the best way to process this data in python and get the desired result?

Comment: Please post a larger example of data. How are next entries separated?

Comment: As of now input data block is continuous without seperation. There are hundreds of blocks like the one i mentioned

Comment: Not even empty lines? So basically every entry starts with `Name`?

Comment: Actually there is a bigger report and iam processing out this data to a seperate text file. As of now i didn't add any seperation between blocks of data.

Comment: @Cod3r could you try the approach in my answer and lemme know if that works?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines)

vals = []
for line in lines:
    vals.append(line.rpartition(':')[2].strip()) <-- this would basically split your string by colon

row = ",".join(vals) <-- this is the one you can use
print(row)
```

Output:

> ['Name : John Doe\n', 'age  : 30\n', 'Job  : Accountant']
>
> John Doe,30,Accountant

Also you can write it to a csv like this:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as out:
    lines = [line for line in row.split(',')]
    my_string = ','.join(lines)
    out.write(my_string)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you would want a newline after each record in the CSV file. So this should do the trick:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f_in:
    lines = (line for line in f_in)
    with open('csv_out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
            # Obtain required data without any white space
            line = line.strip().split(':')[1][1:]
            if line_num % 3 == 0:
                # On every 3rd line add a newline; else add the required comma between the fields
                line += '\n'
            else:
                line += ','
            f_out.write(line)
```

I'm also assuming your source file is exactly as you state in your question. But, if you *don't* have spaces between the colon, simply remove the [1:] slice from line 6.

Using a generator comprehension in the second line means that there is no need to load the entire source file into memory, which means it doesn't matter how big your source file is (which may or may not be relevant to you).

If you wanted the source in memory for some reason (now or later), you can replace the second line with:

```
lines = f_in.readlines()
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read in the text file
df = pd.read_csv("input.txt", delimiter='\t')

# Make any necessary edits to the DataFrame

# Export the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: This doesn't help with my problem.